# How to schedule rselenium - rvest scraping script in aws ec2 windows instance

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, docker, rvest, rselenium

I have web scraping script. My script is using rselenium and rvest packages.

Currently i am running my script in my local machine with the help of docker.

I tried to run same setup in aws ec2 instance.  But I am unable to that.  I am unable to set virtual machine enable setup in aws. So docker is not working.

Could you please guide me to setup my script in aws or any cloud platform.

Comment: This is a system-ops related question, please share the exact error you are facing while setting up the ec2 instance and during deployment of your script. Is it bare metal machine deployment, then on which OS, ubuntu/centOS, which version etc. If it is kubernetes , then share the details accordingly

Comment: Docker works perfectly fine on EC2